# Having a Server progress two threads at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, server

I have two threads reaching a point in the server program at slightly differing times, both sending a string. I want the server to pause at this point until both threads have received a string and then continue. Currently I am using `Console.ReadKey();` in order to "pause" the thread. But this isn't a solution as I need to press a key twice (one for each thread) in order to progress.

Is there a possibility of having a global counter in the program class which is accessible and editable by all threads at all times? A similiar concept to a `ConcurrentDictionary`. That way I can distinguish between threads based on which thread sent a string first and make the program hang until the counter is satisfied that both clients have 'answered'.

```
class Program
{
    public static bool isFirstThread = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        runServer();
    }

    static void runServer()
    {
        //server setup
        Thread[] threadsArray = new Thread[2];
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            while(true) //game loop
            {
                Socket connection;
                connection = listener.AcceptSocket();
                threadRequest = new Handler();

                if(i==0) //first thread
                {
                    threadsArray[i] = new Thread(() => threadRequest.clientInteraction(connection, true);
                }
                else //not first thread
                {
                    threadsArray[i] = new Thread(() => threadRequest.clientInteraction(connection, false);
                }

                threadsArray[i].Start();
                i++;
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
}


class Handler 
{
    public void clientInteraction(Socket connection, bool isFirstThread)

    {
        string pAnswer = string.Empty;
        //setup streamReaders and streamWriters

        while(true) //infinite game loop
        {
            //read in a question and send to both threads.
            pAnswer = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(pAnswer);

            Console.ReadKey(); //This is where I need the program to hang

            awardPoints(); 

        }
    }
}
```

This is a rough idea of what my code is doing, I've chopped quite a bit to avoid question bloat so there might be a couple of things that are in error that I've missed.

I could in theory just set a timer from when the question string is sent from the server, but I would rather not at this stage.

Any thoughts or pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A while loop with a condition? A variable is usually editable by multiple threads, except for when the race condition is performed. But if you want to wait, use a while loop with a boolean condition.

Comment: where would this variable be declared? I've experimented with putting one in the program class but unless I pass it when the thread is created, that doesnt work. and at the time the threads are created, the condition of the proposed while loop isn't known

Comment: Do you want both threads to continue at the same time, or only one? You could always pass the variable as a `ref` parameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`System.Threading.Barrier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier(v=vs.110).aspx), which is designed for this exact purpose: making each thread in a group of threads wait until all of them have reached some point in their computation. Initialize it in `runServer()` like this:

```
Barrier barrier = new Barrier(2);
```

And do this at the end of each thread:

```
barrier.SignalAndWait();
```

Comment: Didn't know about this. Nice!

Comment: absolutely perfect. Much appreciated.

Comment: :-) - there are a lot of goodies in `System.Threading` - another personal favorite is the `AutoResetEvent` for making one thread wait until another thread sends it a signal.